# Take a list including numbers and convert it to min/max version

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Take a list of numbers and then creates another list which includes
pairs with are created by selecting a minimum number and a maximum number until no number is left in the list.

Input:

```
[3,6,1,8,7,9,12,4]
```

Output:

```
[(1,12),(3,9),(4,8),(6,7)]
```

How is it possible to do this?

Should I use `transpose` and `fromIntegral` functions?

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: I literally could not find how to do it.I could not combine with my limited knowledge.

Comment: take a look at `sort`.

Comment: I do not really follow why you should need `transpose` or `fromIntegral`? What should happen if the list has an odd number of values? Then there is a value "in the middle" that can not be wrapped into a 2-tuple.

Comment: I have limited knowlegde ,so i thought those can be used for solution. :(  I am about to understand the mentality of language.If i find a code explaining that function , many scenes will more clear.

Comment: Hint.. `sort` the list and `zip` it with it's `reverse`d version... Then think a way to calculate howmany to `take`.

Comment: A similar approach would be to turn it into a `Seq`, `sort` that, then write a function which peels off the front and back elements simultaneously.

Comment: @Coderer: can you please make a fair attempt with the hints given in the comment and update the question with specific questions about what is not working with that attempt?

Comment: How should it behave with odd number of elements?

Comment: It's possible to do this because Haskell is good at these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution. Note that it will drop the middle element if the list has odd length.

```
import Data.List(sort)

fun :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, a)]
fun l =
  let x = sort l
  in take (length l `div` 2) (zip x (reverse x))
```

---

First we sort `l` in ascending order. Therefore considering your example `[3,6,1,8,7,9,12,4]`:

```
x == [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,12]
```

We `zip` `x` with reversed `x`:

```
zip x (reverse x) == [(1,12),(3,9),(4,8),(6,7),(7,6),(8,4),(9,3),(12,1)]
```

And then we take first half of the elements, that is `` length l `div` 2 ``:

```
take (length l `div` 2) (zip x (reverse x))
 == [(1,12),(3,9),(4,8),(6,7)]
```

Comment: You may also consider using `takeWhile (uncurry (<))` to eliminate `length`.

Comment: If that's a concern then make it `(<=)`.

Comment: Then you may take too much :p

Comment: If that's a concern then make it `nub . sort`. The context is the question is not open to debate.